# Is it possible to only show iAds on first launch

Tags: ios, iad

I have a free app that I suspect is only launched by the majority of its users a couple times before its deleted. Is it possible to only show an iAd banner on the first launch of the application, or maybe only implement iAd until after the first ad is filled?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to show ads on first launch only.

Comment: Does that seem like a reasonable thing to do given the typical use case?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Especially when i know that my app get's deleted very soon i would want to show as many ads as possible (without making the user angry of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a value that you can check and see if the application has been launched before.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Show iAd on first run
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {

        // iAd code here

        // Update NSUserDefaults
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
    }
}
```

I can't imagine a scenario where you would want to limit your ad revenue to just the initial run though.

Comment: I ran the numbers and most users don't run the app more than once, might as well reward the users who like it by removing the ads.